# not getting the double for-loops python to work

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some content, but I cannot get a double for-loop to work. I tried look up other examples/solutions but I am getting no luck on my own. Using `python3x` and `BS4`.

Context:
In the html content there is a **container** containing 11x (`"div",{"class":"days"}`)

Within this class, there can be 1-8x (`"div",{"class":"item"}`)
Of this item, i want to have the '`name`' and '`description`' fields

```
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
days = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"days"})

for item in days.findAll("div",{"class":"item"}):
    name = item.h3.a.text
    description = item.h4.a.text
    print(name, description)
```

This give me the error `AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'.` When I add `days = days[0]` it provides me the correct details of the first 'days'. But now I want it to loop through all 11 'days', how do I loop through these 'days'?

Comment: You are setting `days = [0]` - that's not your intention. *"gives me result from the first 'days"* is not what that line does.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. I used 'days = days[0]' to check the results, and the results look good, but it is just for that first 'days'. When i remove it i get 'AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'. ?'

Comment: Ahh, I see. OK. Now you ask: *"but now I want it to loop through all 11 'days', how do I loop through these 'days'?"* - How are you looping through the items right now? Could you use the same way?

Comment: Hmmm I tried this at least ten times and it faild, but now that I tried this again for providing an example; it seems to be working. Maybe I made a typo before? Thanks for the quick response

 `for days in page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"days"}):
 for item in page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item"}):
  name = item.h3.a.text
  description = item.h4.a.text
  print(name,description)`

Comment: That's almost it. :) Final two hints: 1) You don't have to  call `.findAll()` at the root of the document tree. You can call it at *any* element in the tree. 2) The `for` loop gives you *one* item a time, i.e. it should not read `for days in ...`, but `for day in ...`.